# Dropdownmenu Delay not working

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I need a delay on my dropdownmenu. i tried to use, hoverintent but its not working, cant find my error.

My CSS:

[CSS](http://pastie.org/3621320)

My Dropdown:

```
<div id="menu" class="menu"><ul><li class="first"><a href=index.php" title="Home"     >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=13" title="Verein" >Verein</a><ul><li class="first"><a href="index.php?id=33" title="Vorstand" >Vorstand</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=5" title="Mitglieder" >Mitglieder</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="index.php?id=6" title="Anfahrt" >Anfahrt</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=7" title="Kontakt" >Kontakt</a><ul><li class="first"><a href="/content/Anmeldung_OG_Schau_17_06_2012.doc" title="Ortsgruppenschau"     >Ortsgruppenschau</a>/li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=16" title="Hunde" >Hunde</a><ul><li class="first"><a href="index.php?id=10" title="Hundeschule" >Hundeschule</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=9" title="Hundesport" >Hundesport</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="index.php?id=31" title="Rassen" >Rassen</a><ul><li class="first"><a href="index.php?id=19" title="Riesenschnauzer" >Riesenschnauzer</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=20" title="Schnauzer" >Schnauzer</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=28" title="Zwergschnauzer" >Zwergschnauzer</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=29" title="Deutscher Pinscher" >Deutscher Pinscher</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=30" title="Zwergpinscher" >Zwergpinscher</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="index.php?id=32" title="Affenpinscher" >Affenpinscher</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=25" title="Galerie" >Galerie</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=27" title="Presse" >Presse</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=34" title="Termine" >Termine</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="index.php?id=35" title="Links" >Links</a></li>
<li class="last"><a href="index.php?id=36" title="Impressum" >Impressum</a></li>
</ul></div></div>
```

My js call:

```
$(function(){

var config = {    
     sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
     interval: 200,  // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
     over: doOpen,   // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
     timeout: 2000,   // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
     out: doClose    // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
};

function doOpen() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
}

function doClose() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    alert("test");
}

$(".menu ul li").hoverIntent(config);

$(".menu ul li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

});
```

If i go over the dropdown menu its saying the test, so it finding the function and there is no error in it, but its not working. How can i get that fixed?

Demo: [Demo](http://hanfrey.bplaced.net/)

Comment: There is not animation called here.. Could you please provide us with a demo?!!

Comment: first fix your html to be valid..  (*unclosed quotes, missing `<` chars etc..*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three things.

Your CSS is working without the JS. You need to rewrite the `:hover` of the dropdown ul to `.hover`

On the demo you have `$(".test ul li")` and not `$(".menu ul li")`. Will not work because ul has class test and is not child of class test

doOpen and doClose must be defined before they are used in conig.

Comment: [link](http://hanfrey.bplaced.net/SimplejQueryDropdowns/index-hoverIntent.html), here is it working with config first declared! so cant be the error. im trying at the moment with the demo to get that working. what do you mean with rewrite the :hover?

Comment: line 56 of your ultimatedrop.ccs: instead of `.menu ul li:hover ul, .menu ul li a:hover ul` you need to use `.menu ul li.hover ul, .menu ul li a.hover ul` (class hover instead of pseudoelement :hover)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I will if I know what the answer is.

Comment: Then i got no hover effect. I changed now the complete css and its working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user1010775 You want the hover effect with JS not with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the order in which you call your functions, maybe.

Try having config after the functions doOpen and doClose

```
$(function(){

    function doOpen() {
        $(this).addClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }

    function doClose() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

    }

    var config = {    
         sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
         interval: 200,  // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
         over: doOpen,   // function = onMouseOver callback (REQUIRED)    
         timeout: 2000,   // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
         out: doClose    // function = onMouseOut callback (REQUIRED)    
    };

    $(".menu ul li").hoverIntent(config);

    $(".menu ul li ul li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append(" &raquo; ");

});
```